# Luxon produces invalid dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, luxon

I have this date:

```js
const fromDate = "Sat Oct 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+04:00)";
```

I want to change it to be in a specific timezone, this is how I tried:

```js
const newDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(fromDate).setZone("Asia/Amman").toJSDate()
```

I also tried:

```js
const newDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(fromDate, { zone: "Asia/Amman" }).toJSDate()
```

But both ways are producing invalid dates!

```
Invalid Date
```

ISO `fromDate` also failed.

So, what is going on here?

Comment: I’m a little confused how a time stamp can be in two time zones?

Comment: @evolutionxbox ah, nevermind. It was just for testing. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrapping `fromDate` with `new Date()` fixes the problem. Since the function expects a date object; not a string.